# How to execute a command(with arguments) in ubuntu 10.04 environment

Tags: java, linux, runtime, exec, ubuntu-10.04

I've a created an standalone application in which my aim is to execute a command(with arguments Eg: gedit filename). How to do this through java programming. I tried the following piece of code, but its not working.

```
String[] command = new String[]{"gedit", "abc"};  
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations on the exec() command and also used JavaProcessBuilder many times but I seem to get no solution for this. Can anyone please help me with this. Please try to give the code, I've already visited many links but all in vain. Please help.
-Thanks in advance

Comment: your code seems ok, can you tell us what is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the full qualified path to gedit (e.g /home/user/bin/gedit)

Comment: Instead of "/home/user/bin/gedit" its only "/usr/bin/gedit". Anyways thanks a lot Stacker, You really have given me the best possible solution.